# how to get jobject in invokeshutdown method

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I am trying to write windows service for my Java server. Here is how I have written my `invokeshutdown` method. But I am confused on how i will get `jobject` reference here.

```
DWORD WINAPI InvokeShutdown( LPVOID lpParam ) {
    JNIEnv *env;
    jclass cls;
    jmethodID mid;
    //Since the JVM was created in a another thread. We have to attach the thread 
    //to JVM before making " calls
    vm->AttachCurrentThread((void **)&env, 0); 
    cls = env->FindClass("com.my.internal.Launcher");
    // Create the argument list.
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, "-dir=stop");

    mid = env->GetMethodID(env, cls, "stop", "()V");

    env->CallVoidMethodV(env, obj, mid, args);

    vm->DetachCurrentThread();
    Log( "Detached thread\n");
    return 0;
}
```

how do i get `obj` in `env->CallVoidMethodV(env, obj, mid, args);`

Answer (score 1):

I wonder why don't you make the 'shutdown method' (`stop`) static instead? Then you can call it within `InvokeShutdown` by something like this...

```
  cls = env->FindClass("com.my.internal.Launcher");
  mid = env->GetStaticMethodID(cls, "stop", "()V");
  env->CallStaticVoidMethod(cls, mid, 0);
  vm->DetachCurrentThread();
```

You can create an object instead with `NewObject` instead, and use this object to call its method, but it would be a bit... redundant, I suppose.